# Shade Smooth in Sverchok?

Tags: mesh, normals, sverchok

When I try to animate or tweak my nodes, the mesh automatically switches back to *flat* shading despite I have set it to *smooth* previously.

[image]

**Q:** How can I set the shading to *Smooth* when using *Sverchok*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Enable smooth shading on the Mesh Viewer properties]

You have to enable smooth shade on the Mesh Viewer properties (in the N-panel)

Comment: Thank you so much!